# How to pass command line arguments to a url string

Tags: python, sys

I have a report I'm downloading from a url using requests in python like this:

```
dls = 'http://somepage/reporting?tags=name&daysback=days'
resp = requests.get(dls)
```

What I want is for 'tag' and 'daysback' in the url above to be arguments passed in the command line using sys argv.

For example, I want something like this:

```
try:
     tag = sys.argv[1]
     daysback = sys.argv[2]
except IndexError:
     raise IndexError('Example/ python script.py [tag] [daysback]')
```

So if my tag name was 'produce' and 'daysback' was 10, for example:

I'd expect the url to look like this:

```
dls = 'http://somepage/reporting?tags=produce&daysback=10'
```

and command line argument to be:

```
python script.py [produce] [10]
```

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: Why do you want to do `python script.py [produce] [10]` instead of just `python script.py produce 10`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import sys

tag = sys.argv[1]
daysback = sys.argv[2]

url = 'http://somepage/reporting?tags=' + tag + '&daysback=' + daysback

resp = requests.get(url)
```

Alternatively:

```
url = 'http://somepage/reporting?tags={}&daysback={}'.format(tag, daysback)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was missing the str wrapper

Comment: @Hana You can get rid of the `str()` calls if you pass them as strings (i.e. `"produce" "10"`).

Comment: You don't need—or want—the `str` calls here. `sys.argv` is always a list of strings (in both Python 2 and Python 3). (And the shell is always passing them in as strings because the shell doesn't know anything but strings.)

Comment: @Hana The part you were missing is that `+` to concatenate strings together.